# VNET secured VM is not opening with Bastion

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, vnet, azure-bastion

I have setup Virtual network and required subnets in a resource group.
I have created a VNET secured VM, a Bastion subnet and Bastion service. Bastion service is attached with a public IP address.

I am trying to open my VM through bastion, but it gives me below connection error:

APP.DIALOG_HEADER_CONNECTION_ERROR

CLIENT.TEXT_CLIENT_STATUS_301
[image]
Error page is attached in this thread.

Please let me know if anyone has experienced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> VM through bastion, but it gives me below connection error:
>
> APP.DIALOG_HEADER_CONNECTION_ERROR     CLIENT.TEXT_CLIENT_STATUS_301

This error usually occurs, if NSG and Network interface are not configured properly and if the private link is attached to the virtual network:

To resolve this issue, ensure that network interface is attached to NSG and virtual network add NSG port 443,80:

[image]

[image]

Make sure your Bastion Virtual Network is not attached to any private endpoint and any private link.

[image]

Created virtual machine and deployed bastion in vm like below:

[image]

Now, using virtual machine bastion is connected successfully:

[image]

If still error persist, check this [reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/q8n4k6/need_some_help_with_azure_bastion_service/) by scuffyinoz

Answer (score -1):

The error message you received, **APP.DIALOG_HEADER_CONNECTION_ERROR** **CLIENT.TEXT_CLIENT_STATUS_301** suggests that there may be an issue with the connection between the Bastion service and your VM. The error code "CLIENT_STATUS_301" typically indicates a redirection error.

One of the potential solution has been shared already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725413/azure-bastion-and-private-link-in-the-same-virtual-network-access-to-virtual-ma) but another thing to say is Azure Bastion uses an HTML5 web client via your browser and a TLS connection over port 443.

Considering the above and trying to help you into the troubleshooting process, I would take into the equation as well:

- A browser problem
- A networking problem:

  1. Did you verify if the Bastion service and the VM are in the same virtual network and the same region?
  2. Did you you enable the "Bastion" on the VM?
  3. Did you check network security groups (NSGs) and route tables? Ensure that the NSGs associated with the VM and the Bastion subnet allow the necessary inbound and outbound traffic.

Please, try to:

- A different browser
- A different network (e.g. at home instead of on the corporate network or mobile data instead of fixed internet)
- Verify the above suggested network checks
- Review the diagnostic logs. Azure Bastion generates diagnostic logs that can provide additional information about connection errors. You can access these logs in Azure Monitor or Azure Log Analytics to help troubleshoot the issue further.

If the issue persists, log a support ticket.